# Is it possible to put a dim on a Windows 8 background picture?

Tags: windows, image

I have been searching for a while to see if it is possible to put a dim on a Windows background picture?
 I've seen that people suggested Windows Style builder, but this has a price.
Yet, I'm thinking about putting a dim directly on the picture itself by using Photoshop.
Any suggestions?

I have put this question here because I had no idea where to put it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick's `modulate` command to reduce the brightness and/or saturation of the image like this:

```
convert input.jpg -modulate 40 output.jpg
```

Changing this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Or you could darken and desaturate like this:

```
convert input.jpg -modulate 50,30 output.jpg
```

[image]

turning into:

[image]

Comment: Is this a third-party program that lets you do this to pictures? 
If so, what kind of program do I need?